# Add current section to beamer headline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes

I am currently using the standard Pittsburgh theme for my presentation in LaTeX beamer. Is there a way to include the current section into the headline of my slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet of code will do the job.

```
\documentclass [hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},xcolor={table,pdftex}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=darkred,bg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\begin{beamercolorbox}%
    [sep=0.3cm,wd=\paperwidth]%   
    {frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex
    \leavevmode{%
   \usebeamerfont{fametitle}%
    \begin{footnotesize}
    \insertsection
    \end{footnotesize}\hfill\insertframetitle\par}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }


\begin{document}
\section{Testsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, always provide complete MWEs.